# Add custom CSS to Leaflet CircleMarker

Tags: css, leaflet

I have a `circleMarker` as follows:

```
var marker = L.circleMarker([11, 11], {
    dashArray: "27",
    color: 'black',
    fillColor: 'white',
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    radius: 135,
}).addTo(map);
```

My goal is to add custom CSS to the marker as follows:

```
.color_shadow {
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow:
      inset 0 0 50px #fff,
      inset 20px 0 80px red,
      inset -20px 0 80px #0ff,
      inset 20px 0 300px red,
      inset -20px 0 300px #0ff,
      0 0 50px #fff,
      -10px 0 80px red,
      10px 0 80px #0ff;
 }
```

With these in place, I tried adding the `color_shadow` class to the marker using the following line of code:

```
L.DomUtil.addClass(marker._path, 'color_shadow');
```

However, this does not appear to work. Can anyone suggest the correct way to add custom CSS to the marker?